# Get data from api using clojure and log result

Tags: clojure

I'm very new to clojure and I familiar with java and PHP. I have assign new clojure job to get data from outside API and do some process.

This my API request and i tried it using curl command
`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"uid\":\"uId\", \"param\":\"1\"}" http://localhost:8081/api/getData`

**result is - {"comp":true ,"yUi":"78.2555","xUi":"4.5233","id":"10"}**

I have apply above process using clojure and i need log those return values.Could you please help me to do this using clojure

**This is how i tried this**

```
(defn- get-data
  "api call"
  [uId]
  (try
    (log/info (trs "start process: {0}" (str "uid" uId )))
    (when-let [ui (client/post "http://localhost:8081/api/getData" {:form-params {:uid uId,:param "1"} :content-type :json })]
      (log/info (trs "get data: {0} {1} {2} {3}" (:comp ui) (:yUi ui) (:xUi ui) (:id ui))))
    (catch Throwable e
      (log/error "api call failed:" (.getMessage e)))))
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Please add your problem statement. From a first glance, i'd guess, that using form-data instead of a json body would be problematic?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which HTTP client library you are using, we can't guess from the namespace alias `client` alone. It would appear the use of `client/post` in the code does not match at all with the `curl` command given.

Comment: The curl command sends data in JSON format using the application/json Content-Type header. It isn't clear what http client the post is using, but  generally using form params will result in a different and probably incorrect data encoding method and Content-Type than the curl. Check the documentation for the client library for the incantation to send data to an API, which will give a template for sending JSON with the correct header.

Comment: Assuming you are using `clj-http` you are probably getting the whole response body as a single string. You can try coercing the response to JSON or a Clojure data structure with `:as json` or `:as clojure`, as shown here: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#output-coercion